# Populate asp:FileUpload from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind

Is it possible to populate `asp:FileUpload` from code behind?

I have a search form which user can populate using `upload_default_parameters()` method and therefore I also want to populate the fileUpload control from code-behind with a file on server if user opt to use the default parameters.

Comment: do you want a local file to be populated in the control?

Comment: So you want to use fileupload control from code-behind, I guess.

Comment: Yes. I want to upload a local file from code-behind.

Comment: Are you sure about the file path that it will be same in case of all user, and they will have surely have file ?

Comment: The file will be on the server. So, yeah the path will be same for all the users. I'll probably use a flag to differentiate this file from the one user will upload from his/her computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot do this from codebehind fileUpload.filename is a readonly and you cannot set values to it. You might be able to achieve this using JS